# TabBar Item badgeValue is updated but with delay

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, badge, tabitem

```
[tabViewController.tabBarItem setBadgeValue : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",totalUnreadMessages]];
```

Everything works but it takes at least 10 seconds to be updated. Is there any reason why this could be happening? Is there anyway to force an update?

Comment: When are you calling this?  Can you post the code surrounding your `setBadgeValue` code?

Comment: why down vote? it is called from within

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,(unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) 
{

[self updateMessageTabBadge];

});


in appDelegate after server response?

Comment: Is dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {} required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't perform UI updates on the global queue - that's why you're experiencing the long delay before anything happens.  If you're receiving the server response on a background queue, use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)...` to update your UI.

If you aren't receiving the server response on a background thread, you don't need to use dispatch_async at all.

Comment: thanks for explanation. I assume that dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) would/can be done within global queue.

Comment: Yes... if you're inside of a block that is dispatched on the global queue, you can use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) to call back to the main thread for UI updates.